# Manipulating the maximum function, metric spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to show that the supremum metric, $d_{\infty}$, is indeed a metric on $\mathbb R^2$. I have shown that the first two properties of a metric space hold, but am having trouble showing the third, namely that for any points $A,B,C\in \mathbb R^2$ then,

$$d_\infty(A,B)\le d_\infty(A,C)+d_\infty(C,B)$$

Here is what I have done so far:

$$d_\infty(A,B)=\max(|a_1-b_1|,|a_2-b_2|)$$

$$=\max(|a_1+c_1-c_1-b_1|,|a_2+c_2-c_2-b_2|)$$

$$\le\max(|a_1-c_1|+|c_1-b_1|,|a_2-c_2|+|c_2-b_2|)$$

Now, I know what it is that I should be getting, but I am not sure how to manipulate the $\max$ function to get it. Can somebody guide me through the next step to see what to do with the $\max$ function to obtain,

$$=\max(|a_1-c_1|,|a_2-c_2|)+\max(|c_1-b_1|,|c_2-b_2|)$$

$$=d_\infty(A,C)+d_\infty(C,B)$$

$$\iff d_\infty(A,B)\le d_\infty(A,C)+d_\infty(C,B)$$

Comment: Start with $\lvert a_1 - c_1\rvert \leqslant \lvert a_1 - b_1\rvert + \lvert b_1 - c_1\rvert$. See that the right hand side is $\leqslant d_\infty(A,B) + d_\infty(B,C)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{\color{red}{|a_1-c_1|}+\color{red}{|c_1-b_1|}}_{\clubsuit}\leq&\,\underbrace{\max\{\color{red}{|a_1-c_1|},|a_2-c_2|\}+\max\{\color{red}{|c_1-b_1|},|c_2-b_2|\}}_{\star},\\
\underbrace{\color{blue}{|a_2-c_2|}+\color{blue}{|c_2-b_2|}}_{\diamondsuit}\leq&\,\underbrace{\max\{|a_1-c_1|,\color{blue}{|a_2-c_2|}\}+\max\{|c_1-b_1|,\color{blue}{|c_2-b_2|}\}}_{\star}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
&\,\max\{\underbrace{|a_1-c_1|+|c_1-b_1|}_{\clubsuit},\underbrace{|a_2-c_2|+|c_2-b_2|}_{\diamondsuit}\}\\
\leq&\,\underbrace{\max\{|a_1-c_1|,|a_2-c_2|\}+\max\{|c_1-b_1|,|c_2-b_2|\}}_{\star}.
\end{align*}